# How do i wrap all my code in imageBackground

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following and i have all the imports added. Please see below code (apologies as a bit of a newbie)

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../../assets/logo.png')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='E-mail'
                    placeholderTextColor="#CBB26A"
                    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                    value={email}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#CBB26A"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                    value={password}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Log in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>              
                <View style={styles.footerView}>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Don't have an account? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>Sign up</Text></Text>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I want to add a background image to cover everything but still make everything work as normal (so it all sits on top of the image). i cant wrap them with imageBackground because of objects. Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'imageBackground because of objects'? adding the imageBackground as the wrapper should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your style and then merge your style with the `styles.container`.

```
const wrapperStyle = {
    ...styles.container,
    background: // your code here
}
```

Then use this `wrapperStyle` into your `View` as

```
<View style={wrapperStyle}>
```

Comment: Hi Sifat, are you able to provide an example of it in my code above at all as im unsure how to place this?

Comment: ignore me i got it to work with the below

    const wrapperstyle = {
        ...styles.container, backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
    return(
    <View style={wrapperstyle}></View>
    )